# Android-Which method is called when I press Esc button on keyboard?

Tags: android, android-activity

I use **hardware Keyboard**  to enter my data in the emulator. I use `Esc` to return to the previous Activity.Now I have 2 questions:

1-Is `Esc` the [image: back button] back button at a real cellphone?

2- To understand which method is called when i press `Esc` i added this code to the Activity, but it looks like none of them are not called

```
    public void onRestart()
    {
        super.onRestart();
        System.out.println("onRestart..."); 
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("onResume..."); 
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("onPause..."); 
    }

    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        System.out.println("onStop..."); 
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("onDestroy...");
    }
```

Comment: @Gung Foo-Thanks for edite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onBackPressed()` is called when you press back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

**EDIT:**

In the above piece of code because of the line `super.onBackPressed()`, the present activity gets closed and the previous activity comes to the foreground.

You can remove `super.onBackPressed()` from the function and check that even when back is pressed, the current activity doesn't get closed.

Comment: -Ok, but what method will be called by this _onBackPressed()_ to start again the previous Activity?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
}
```

called when you press esc .

Answer (score 0):

neither of them. You have to implement `View.OnKeyListener` inteface and attach that implemenation on a Object that use the Keyboard (an `EditText` for instance). The `onKey` method of `OnKeyListener` will be fired